How to protect wsl2 vhdx file with password?
I have a wsl2 vhdx file. I'm working on developing websites with sensitive user data such as emails, phone numbers. How can I protect this vhdx file in case my laptop is stolen so that even when booted from a Linux live usb this wsl2 file cannot be found or accessed? Or found but couldn't be read or opened. Currently, I'm using Bitlocker encrypting the entire D drive where the vhdx file is stored. But is there any other way to protect this file? I've tried simple programs that hide files or directories. But in Linux they are still visible. Maybe is there any way to set password in wsl2 to protect opened instance? Because if start wsl2 - explorer give access to home directories and files can be grabbed.
